# Charlie slept through geography at school

Tags: geography

**Scene One: Charlie meets Benny**

> ADAM: Charlie, I'd like you to meet my friend Benny.
>   BENNY: Hi! Nice to meet you!
>   CHARLIE: Nice to meet you Benny! So, where are you from?
>   BENNY: I'm from [*my country*].
>   CHARLIE: Hehe, I have no idea where that is. Is it near [*other country*]?
>   BENNY: Yeah, that's right! It's right next to [*other country*]. I live in [*my city*].
>   CHARLIE: Is that, like, a big city?
>   BENNY: I think it's slightly bigger than your home city, population-wise at least.
>   CHARLIE: You know I'm from LA, right? We've got like 17 million people.
>   BENNY: Yeah, that's right.
>   CHARLIE: *(laughs)* That's crazy. I think there are like two or three cities in the *world* that are bigger than LA. New York City, and maybe Tokyo, right?
>   BENNY: Whatever you say. *(smiles)*

**Scene Two: Charlie meets Dave**

> CHARLIE: Nice to meet you, Dave. Where are you from?
>   DAVE: I'm from [*my city*], in [*my country*].
>   CHARLIE: Ah, you must know Benny? He's from [*Benny's country*] too.
>   DAVE: Hehe, I said [*my city*], not [*Benny's country*]. [*Benny's country*] is a separate country.
>   CHARLIE: Oh, right. I know Benny has a lot of friends from [*your country*]. With the same language and everything. I hear them talk all the time with each other, but I don't understand a word. *(laughs)*
>   DAVE: Actually, I don't understand those guys either, we speak English with each other. We speak a completely different language in [*my city*].
>   CHARLIE: Huh. But they're from [*your country*] too.
>   DAVE: Yeah. But [*my country*]'s pretty big.

**Scene Three: Charlie meets Eddie**

> CHARLIE: Nice to meet you, Eddie! Where are you from?
>   EDDIE: Well, West Africa originally, but I've lived here for years. We moved here from [*my city*] with my parents when I was nine.
>   CHARLIE: [*Your city*]? I think Benny's from there as well. Do you know him?
>   EDDIE: *(laughs)* Sure, I know him. But he's from [*Benny's country*], right? [*My city*] is in a completely different part of the globe.
>   CHARLIE: I'm pretty sure I heard him say [*your city*].
>   EDDIE: That's weird. Why would he say that?
>   CHARLIE: No idea. Maybe I'm just confused. *(shrugs)*

Can you guess Benny, Dave and Eddie's home cities?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let me try:

Benny:

> Dhaka, Bangladesh
>   
>   Big city, population: 8,063,000 vs LA: 3,976,322
>   Many people speak English here

Dave:

> Bangalor,  India
>   
>   Bangalor sounds a bit like Bangladesh
>   
>   India is a huge country with many languages. Bengali is spoken only in a small part. So here too they speak a lot of English with each other.

Eddie:

> Dakar, Senegal
>   
>   Dakar sound a bit like Dhaka. And it is located in West Africa. 
>   
>   Dakar and Dhaka are 11.000km apart from each other.

Comment: Care to explain the reasoning?

Comment: @jafe, sure, but it seems KillianDS beat me to it :)

Answer (score 3):

The question has already been answered, but I'd just like to suggest that maybe, by "LA", Charlie wasn't referring to

> Los Angeles (as I have initially assumed),

but to

> LAgos, Nigeria which has a population of around 17 million

...which would make Charlie just slightly less uneducated :-)